# Can I publish targeting linux-armv6 runtime in .NET Core 7?

Tags: .net-core

According to [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/7764) and [this runtime list](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v7.0.0/src/libraries/Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms/src/runtime.json) for .NET Core v7.0, `linux-armv6` is supported. However, when I try to target it with `dotnet publish -r linux-armv6` I get the following error:

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets(135,5): error NETSDK1084: There is no application host available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'linux-armv6'.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`armv6` in `dotnet` is only community supported. You can build it by yourself. If you want, I've build it from 7.0.0 source and put it in docker image for building my project. (I use linux-armv6/self contained)

https://hub.docker.com/r/taphome/dotnet7armv6

From my experience, `dotnet` is working pretty well on `armv6`. Problem is if you have some Nugets with native libraries which probably doesn't have `armv6` version of native dependencies. I switched my app.libraries from mono/netstandard20 to net7 on armv6.

Edit:
In https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/7764 is mentioned that you should use `<RuntimeFrameworkVersion>7.0.0-ci</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>` in csproj. With latest my build from it's no longer needed, it's build from 7.0 release branch and has proper version.

After some experience I don't recommend using net6.0 class libraries in csproj, it seems to have some problems with publishing/trimming. Use up to net5.0 or net7.0.

Comment: Can you publish build instructions? `docker run` does not complete it for me. Is there any parameters I need to specify?

Comment: I've build it according to steps mentioned in this issue: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/7764 I will try to build it for net8 also when it'll be out

Comment: But you can use my docker to compile your sources using `docker publish` and self contained. That's how I use it. My build script ```#!/bin/bash

script_dir=$( cd -- "$( dirname -- "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" &> /dev/null && pwd )

docker run --pull always --rm -v ${script_dir}:/src -w /src taphome/dotnet7armv6:latest dotnet publish myProject.csproj -r linux-armv6 --self-contained true -c Release_ARMv6 -f net7.0 -o bin/armv6``` - it will create self contained executable which can run on armv6